# How can I access the value of `\pgfdecoratedpathlength` for use later in the document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

Is there anyway that during the decoration process I can save the value of `\pgfdecoratedpathlength` to some macro (via `xdef` or some other mechanism)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you want to store the length of the input path or the length of the path _after_ some decoration process?

Comment: @PaulGaborit i want the input length, assuming that's the entire length of the

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to globally store the path length.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{store path length}{final}{
  \state{final}{
    \xdef\pathlength{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
\tikzset{store path length/.style={
   preaction={decorate,decoration={store path length}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[store path length] (0,0) -- (1in,0) -- (1in,1in);
  \typeout{==> \pathlength}

  \draw[store path length] circle(50pt);
  \typeout{==> \pathlength}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

During compilation, this document writes:

```
==> 144.53998pt
==> 314.19373pt
```

Comment: Argh.  I thought I'd tried something like this.  Only I was mucking around in `\state{initial}`.

Comment: I'm traveling most of today and tomorrow.  I'll look at this a bit closer on Monday.

Comment: I just successfully used your code. It would be great if you could explain a little bit what is happening (pseudo code)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The `store path length` decoration is a fake decoration that only store the total length of the path into `\pathlength`. The `store path length` style apply this decoration as `preaction` to a path.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  get path length/.code={%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgfprocessround\tikz@tmppath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\tikz@tmppath\tikz@discard%
      \global\let#1=\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength%
    }%
  }
}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]
\draw [get path length=\a] (-20, -20) rectangle ++(40, 40);
\node {\a};

\tikzset{shift=(270:100)}
\draw [get path length=\b] circle [radius=50];
\node  {\b};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll have to play with this a bit since you're using several macros I'm unfamiliar with.