# TikZ/pgf: How to Change the Direction of a Path and the Beginning/Origin/Starting Point of the Path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

In my MWE I have a simple path (circle) and I overlay the path - using a `tikz postaction` - with the same path but with another line with and another color.

The reference (thanks [@MarkWibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow)) of the tricky code snippets is in the code. But I do not think that this is relevant for this problem.

The overlay **starts at 3 o'clock** and goes from there **counter-clockwise**.

### Question(s)

1. How can I **influence** the **direction** (**clockwise** or **counter-clockwise**)
2. How can I **influence** the **starting point/origin/beginning** of the path (here it's apparently 3 o'clock)?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247742
% user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  get path length/.code={%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgfprocessround\tikz@tmppath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\tikz@tmppath\tikz@discard%
      \global\let#1=\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347336
% user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\tikzset{myOwnStyle/.style={
  get path length=\pathlength,
  draw=black,
  line width=1mm,
  postaction={
    draw=red,
    line width=2mm,
    dash pattern= on \pathlength/100*#1 off \pathlength/100*(100-#1),
  }
}}


\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,...,100}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n] (0,0) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

If somebody is interested, I made the animated GIF by two steps:

1. Convert multipage PDF to separate GIF files using [this](http://www.online-convert.com/) service.
2. Converting the separate GIFs to an animated GIF using [this](http://gifmaker.me/) or [this](http://ezgif.com/) (was much faster) service.

I just googled for these kind of service - I did not make any further reseach.

### Update / Edit

After the very helpful answer of [@Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) it was clear that a circle was not a wise choice:) - here's a square.

```
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,100}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5mm,y=1.5mm]]
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n] (0,0) -- (10,0) -- (10,10) -- (0,10) -- cycle;
    \node at (5,5) {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
```

[image]

Comment: To make animated GIF from PDF, you may use the `convert` utility  (provided by ImageMagick): `convert -delay 1 -density 150 doc.pdf doc.gif`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks - maybe that is more convenient. The online tools are great but it's "a lot" of manual steps. [...] 2 min later: Well, it did not work because of the transparency I guess. It looks like the different frames are "stacked" and then you couldn't read the numbers anymore. But I am sure that I will be able to google that.

Comment: You may use the `fit` and `backgrounds` libraries and append this code to the end of tikzpicture: `\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} \node[fit=(current bounding box),fill=white]{}; \end{pgfonlayer}`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks again. I found another solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676119): **-dispose previous** did the trick.

Comment: With `-dispose previous`, the result is not anti-aliased...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I didn't know that - thanks. Then the **fill=white** solution might be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dash phase` (stored by the `\myOwnStylephase` macro) to define the starting point and with a second custom style (`myOwnStyle revert`) to change direction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,fit,backgrounds}

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247742
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  get path length/.code={%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgfprocessround\tikz@tmppath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\tikz@tmppath\tikz@discard%
      \global\let#1=\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347336
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\tikzset{
  myOwnStyle phase/.store in=\myOwnStylephase,
  myOwnStyle phase=0,
  myOwnStyle/.style={
    get path length=\pathlength,
    draw=black,
    line width=1mm,
    postaction={
      draw=red,
      line width=2mm,
      dash pattern= on \pathlength/100*#1 off \pathlength/100*(100-#1),
      dash phase=-\pathlength/100*\myOwnStylephase,
    }
  },
  myOwnStyle revert/.style={
    get path length=\pathlength,
    draw=black,
    line width=1mm,
    postaction={
      draw=red,
      line width=2mm,
      dash pattern=on 0pt off \pathlength/100*(100-#1) on \pathlength/100*#1 off 0pt,
      dash phase=\pathlength/100*\myOwnStylephase,
    }
  },
}


\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,0,0,0,4,...,100,100,100,100}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[line cap=round]
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n]
    (0,0) ++(90:10mm) arc(90:-270:10mm) (0,0) node {\n\,\%};

    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n,myOwnStyle phase=25]
    (3,0) ++(90:10mm) arc(90:-270:10mm) (3,0) node {\n\,\%};

    \draw[myOwnStyle revert=\n]
    (0,-3) ++(90:10mm) arc(90:-270:10mm) (0,-3) node {\n\,\%};

    \draw[myOwnStyle revert=\n,myOwnStyle phase=25]
    (3,-3) ++(90:10mm) arc(90:-270:10mm) (3,-3) node {\n\,\%};

    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n]
    (-1,-7) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-2,0) -- cycle (0,-6) node {\n\,\%};

    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n,myOwnStyle phase=12.5]
    (2,-7) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-2,0) -- cycle (3,-6) node {\n\,\%};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=2mm,fill=white]{};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - and the **[line cap=round]** is also helpful! And I like **{0,0,0,0,4,...,100,100,100,100}** because it makes an pleasant pause in the animation. Is it correct that **revert** and **phase** are not possible together (option with two arguments) or is there too much of logic?

Comment: To use `revert` and `phase` together, you may use `\draw[myOwnStyle revert=\n,myOwnStyle phase=12.5] ...`. Or do you want a different syntax?

Comment: I didn't understand that this is possible (combining the styles) since every of the three styles (myOwnStyle, myOwnStyle revert, and myOwnStyle phase) hat a postaction and so on. It's obvious that I have to try harder to understand the code (it's complicated to me but that just means that I do not have a programming or math background}) - again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this correct? **myOwnStyle phase** ist "just" an option/parameter whereas **myOwnStyle** is a style that uses the option/parameter **myOwnStyle phase**. And **myOwnStyle revert** is a style again that also can use the option/parameter **myOwnStyle phase**.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Correct.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case of a circle, you can just change flip it around with `xscale=-1` to change the direction, and rotate it to change the starting point, e.g. `\draw[myOwnStyle=\n,rotate=30,xscale=-1]`. This does not apply to sorts of shapes, of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247742
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  get path length/.code={%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgfprocessround\tikz@tmppath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\tikz@tmppath\tikz@discard%
      \global\let#1=\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347336
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\tikzset{myOwnStyle/.style={
  get path length=\pathlength,
  draw=black,
  line width=1mm,
  postaction={
    draw=red,
    line width=2mm,
    dash pattern= on \pathlength/100*#1 off \pathlength/100*(100-#1),
  }
}}


\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,...,100}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n,rotate=30,xscale=-1] (0,0) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that this only works for objects that are symmetrical to rotation. But in this case it is a good idea!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, that is true.

Comment: I updated the question with a better shape - the circle was a stupid choice, sorry.