# Beamer: Centering a tikzpicture in the background (\usebackgroundtemplate)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I really thought that this can't be too hard but I struggle **centering** (vertically and horizontally) **a `tikzpicture` in the `\usebackgroundtemplate`**.

I use the code taken from one of my [previous questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347612) - in the end I want to have a progress indicator in the background of the beamer presentation.

When I use a simple `\begin{center}...\end{center}` (only horizontally) then I get an error saying

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a
>   missing \item.

But `\begin{center}...\end{center}` works in the normal frame (see MWE).

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247742
% user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  get path length/.code={%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgfprocessround\tikz@tmppath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\tikz@tmppath\tikz@discard%
      \global\let#1=\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347336
% user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\tikzset{myOwnStyle/.style={
  get path length=\pathlength,
  draw=black,
  line width=1mm,
  postaction={
    draw=red,
    line width=2mm,
    dash pattern= on \pathlength/100*#1 off \pathlength/100*(100-#1),
  }
}}

% I want to vertically and horizontally center this tikzpicture
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{
%\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n,color=blue] (0,0) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
%\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,10,...,100}{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Number: \n}
This is the frame with the number \n.

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n] (0,0) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resize the `tikzpicture` to the paper using `\useasboundingbox` and position the circle in the center.  There are several mechanisms, I used the coordinate `(.5\paperwidth,.5\paperheight)`.  You could also place it at half the diagonal or something else.

*N.B.:* Do you really want two of these circles on each frame?

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247742
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  get path length/.code={%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgfprocessround\tikz@tmppath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\tikz@tmppath\tikz@discard%
      \global\let#1=\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347336
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\tikzset{myOwnStyle/.style={
  get path length=\pathlength,
  draw=black,
  line width=1mm,
  postaction={
    draw=red,
    line width=2mm,
    dash pattern= on \pathlength/100*#1 off \pathlength/100*(100-#1),
  }
}}

% I want to vertically and horizontally center this tikzpicture
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \draw[myOwnStyle=\n,color=blue] (.5\paperwidth,.5\paperheight) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,10,...,100}{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Number: \n}
This is the frame with the number \n.

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n] (0,0) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - the circles are just for debugging purpuses. I will use a complete different design later (hopefully). I really like the elegancy of the solution! I tried **remember picture** and **overlay** and friends but without success.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and because I didn't figure it out myself :( ) - what would be an alternative approach?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Alternative to what?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, you wrote `[...]There are several mechanisms[...].`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Ah, I see.  You could use the coordinate `(current page.center)` or construct `\path (current page.north west) -- coordinate (mid) (current page.south east)` and use `(mid)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can place it at the centre of the page with

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \draw[myOwnStyle=\n,color=blue] (current page.center) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
   \end{tikzpicture} 
}
```

---

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247742
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  get path length/.code={%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgfprocessround\tikz@tmppath\tikz@tmppath%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath\tikz@tmppath\tikz@discard%
      \global\let#1=\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347336
% user http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow
\tikzset{myOwnStyle/.style={
  get path length=\pathlength,
  draw=black,
  line width=1mm,
  postaction={
    draw=red,
    line width=2mm,
    dash pattern= on \pathlength/100*#1 off \pathlength/100*(100-#1),
  }
}}

% I want to vertically and horizontally center this tikzpicture
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{
%\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n,color=blue] (current page.center) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
%\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,10,...,100}{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Number: \n}
This is the frame with the number \n.

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myOwnStyle=\n] (0,0) circle [radius = 10mm] node {\n\,\%};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the `current page.center` apparently wrong in my own attempts.

Comment: You need to typeset twice for it to show up.

Comment: @HenriMenke `s/typeset/compile/`?